# Run `wp_insert_post_data` on all posts

Tags: filters

I have a bunch of regular expressions that I want to run on my posts to update the `post_content` field, when a series of conditions are met, some of them require a combination of various values from ACF. Long story short I need a way to be able to programmatically edit the content of all my posts using `preg_replace`

I've been learning about the `wp_insert_post_data` filter, and it works, but it only works for the current post that is being edited. Is there any way to do this in WordPress where I can loop through all posts and update the content similarly?

Here's what I currently have.

```php
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'mystuff', 99, 2);
function mystuff($data, $post)
{
    $content = $data['post_content'];
    $regex = '/MYCRAZYREGEXSTUFF/';
    $match = preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
    if ($match) {
        $updatedContent = preg_replace($regex, '', $content);
        $data['post_content'] = $updatedContent;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You can do regex search replace on your whole database with [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/).

Comment: So since I need to be able to query fields to use in my regex replacement value, I can't use a plain DB regex routine.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing a function inside of my template's index.php like this.

```
function fancySearchAndReplace() {
    $regex = '/myregex/';
    $my_posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'numberposts' => -1));
    foreach ($my_posts as $post) {
        $content = $post->post_content;
        $theID = $post->ID;
        $thing = get_field('thing', $theID);
        $updatedContent = preg_replace($regex, $thing, $content);
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $theID,
            'post_content' => $updatedContent,
        ));
    }
}
```